# Find the limit of $s_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find this limit $s_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3n}$ using the fact that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$

So I did it this way:

$$3\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 3\ln(e)^n=3(1^n)=3$$

Comment: and for proving $P_n(x) = (1+x/n)^n \to e^x$  you can show that $\frac{P_n(x)'}{P_n(x)} \to 1$ so that $ln P_n(x) = ln P_n(x) - \ln P_n(0)  \to \int_0^x 1 dt = x$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that 
$  \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3n} =   \left (\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right )^3$

Comment: So it's just $e^3$

Comment: @free_mind right! $x^3$ is a continuous function so...

Comment: That means it is $\infty$

Comment: @free_mind Continuity is used to say the following if $a_n \rightarrow a$ then $ \lim _n (a_n)^3 = (\lim _n a_n)^3  $

Comment: I see. Interestingly I'm working a very similar problem, $s_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$ I get  $\frac{1}{e}$, however, wolfram says it's $\infty$

Comment: Sorry I was editing my comment above

Comment: @free_mind you are absolutely right it is $\frac{1}{e}$, this is indeed strange if you give a link to the wolfram's page with your query perhaps I could say more

Comment: Sure thing... here it is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+((1-1%2Fn)%5En)%5E%7B-1%7D+as+n-%3Einfinity

Comment: I see my mistakes... a minus sign.  Well that didn't change it haha

Comment: @free_mind For some reason Wolfram Alpha is not interpreting your "n -> infinity" correctly (under the limit it says $n \to n$). This works though: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+(1%2B1%2Fn)%5E(-n)